# Visualforce render as Word with Image embedded

Tags: visualforce, ms-word

I would like to know whether it is possible to add an embedded image in Word document when developed from Visualforce page so that when user opens the same document after downloading, the image is displayed even when the user is offline.

Comment: Point of clarity: Visualforce does not render Microsoft Word documents. It renders HTML that Microsoft Word, due to a behavioral quirk, is willing to open and render if you claim it is a Word document. Whether or not this is even possible is dependent on the details of Word's HTML renderer.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen any functionality for rendering Visualforce pages as a .doc, but Salesforce provides some guidance [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314591&type=1&mode=1). You must use `contentType="application/msword#filename.doc"`, `applyHtmlTag="false"`, and `applyBodyTag="false"` in your initial `<apex:page>` tag.

From there, I believe you'd be able to give the image tag it's source as raw, base64 data rather than a URL. This would mean querying for the static resource in the Visualforce page's Apex controller, and possibly manipulating it there, before giving it to the Visualforce page like so:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!yourImageData}"/>
```

Comment: this is not working the image is not been displayed on word document . Can you provide some snippet to get help with the same.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I've never rendered a Visualforce page as a .doc let alone tried to embed an image inside. What've you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried extracting images from the following :1. Files 2. Static resouces 3.Document . But in all the above the image is not rendered on word document and the text is being rendered.

Comment: I should have specified: how're you currently trying to display the image in the Visualforce page? I assume you're using an img tag, and setting the source to a URL? I don't think that will work, as I imagine Word is not able/ permitted to reach out to unknown URLs to fetch images, so you have a better chance if you include the image's raw data instead.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Wareing . Point noted!